# Netbeans 7.3 - how do I prefill '@author' field?

Tags: macos, netbeans, ide, osx-lion, netbeans-7.3

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how to set the @author comment doc code to display my own info in Netbeans.

I want this done for all of my files (js, php, etc).

I have gone to the tools->templates and then click the 'settings' button and uncommented the 'user' variable, entering my own. ie: "user=foo bar ".  without the double quotes, of course.

I would like to type `"/**"` + ENTER and have it insert the comment code such as:

```
/**
 *
 * @author foo bar <foo@bar.com>
 **/
```

I've searched the threads and seems that should do it?

This is for Netbeans 7.3 on OSX 10.8.3.

Answer (score 2):

The user name (as set in your OS) should be set per default.
Please check if the template(s) (**`tools -> Templates (-> Open in Editor)`**) of your file(s) contain such a line:

```
/**
 *
 * @author ${user}
 */
```

*(Taken from Java Class Template)*

or

```
/* 
 * [...]
 * Author: %<%USER%>%
 * [...]
 */
```

*(Taken from C++ Header Template)*

However, you won't get email etc. using this env. variable.

But you can put your full author name (incl. Email) into the template.

Comment: the user name as set in my OS is not used per default. none of the templates I see under tools -> templates even have a '@author' line.

Comment: if you add those line, is the variable set proper?

Comment: I'm not sure which file to actually set so that it'll work on js and php files.